# Why can't I use innerHTML property on variables?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Suppose I have the following html:
`div id="my_div"><span>no no</span></div>`. I want to change the text *no no* with *yes yes*. I can do it as following:

```
document.getElementById("my_div").getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = "yes yes"
```

But if I want to use things as variables like the following:

```
var x = document.getElementById("my_div").getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;    
    x = "yes yes";
```

Now the text *no no* is not changed. Why?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: @NewToJS Yes I have checked in the browser console. It gives no errors.

Comment: Why can you completely changed your question? You know others can just click `edited` under your post to view the original question... This makes `gurvinder372` answer look wrong when `gurvinder372` post is answering your original question. I have flagged this question.

Comment: @NewToJS I thought the question was not clear because it was downvoted. So I made it clear with an easy example.

Comment: You new questions is very different to your original. `innerHTML` for page elements to `object` properties... come on.

Comment: @NewToJS I've actually generalized it. I changed the object `doocument.GetElementById("my_div")` to `obj` object. And the property `innerHTML` to property `len`. Rather than asking for a specific case, now I am asking in general the same thing.

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: @Matt Ok I have asked it as a new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/36865168/3429430 but please don't close that as a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 5):

To change the value, you need to assign a new value to object, while you are assigning a new value to the reference itself.

Try this

```
var x = document.getElementById("my_div").getElementsByTagName('span')[0];    
x.innerHTML = "yes yes";
```

Comment: Isn't `x` an object?

Comment: It is reference to which (first) you assigned an object reference value, which you then replaced with a new value.

Comment: Doesn't `=` act as assignment operator in javascript?

Comment: @user31782 yes, am I missing something?

Comment: I do not understand your answer. What is _Reference_? I am assigning a text string value to the _variable_ x. First I made `x` equal to the innerHTML of `span` element. Then I changed the value of `x`. Since `x` is changed so `span`'s innerHTML should also change.

Comment: when you assign new value `"yes yes"` to `x`, you replaced the older reference value with new one. You are no longer pointing to that DOM object since you have replaced the reference value to it by a new value `"yes yes"`

Comment: In javascript variables are passed by reference. Suppose I have `var x=1, y=2, z=3;` then after `y=x` if I set `y=99` then `x` will also be set to `99`. Similarly in my question, `document.getElementById("my_div").getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML` is passed to `x` by reference. So changing `x` should also change `document.getElementById("my_div").getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: `Suppos I have var x=1, y=2, z=3; then after y=x if I set y=99 then x will also be set to 99` Wrong!! Try this in your browser console.

Comment: Perhaps objects are passed by reference only. But then why does `x.innerHTML = "yes yes"` work? `x` and `document.getElementById("my_div").getElementsByTagName('span')[0]` are different things.

Comment: @user31782 Nope, they are pass by value only. Just that modifying the value is different from assigning a new value.

Comment: IIRC Object's properties are changed by reference when object is passed as argument to a function.

Comment: @user31782 yes, because the value that is passed is a reference value not the actual value itself.

Comment: Isn't reference value and actual value one and the same thing?

Comment: @user31782 reference value is basically the address-value of the actual value.

Comment: Now what is address value? The values at the actual memory location?

Comment: @user31782 Nope, it is the memory-location rather than value-at-memory-location.

Comment: So you mean the statement `var x = document.getElementById("my_div").getElementsByTagName('span')[0]` assigns the memory location of span element's data to `x` variable? Then if `var r=2, s=3;` then `s=r` assigns `r`'s memory location to `s`?

Comment: @user31782 yes, it assigns the reference of RHS to the LHS.

Comment: Then why does `s` become `2`? It should take some hexadecimal value which represent `r`'s memory location.

Comment: @gurvinder372 keep an eye out of any down votes, for some reason **user31782** has changed the question making your answer appear to be incorrect. I have flagged the question for that reason. I would expect better from someone with a rep of **343**

Comment: @NewToJS yes, noticed that.. Thanks for letting me know.