# Are variables/objects passed by value and why can't I change object's property with variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Suppose I have an object as:

```
var obj = {
        len: 4,
        bred: 5
    }
```

Now suppose I assign this object to a variable `x` as `var x = obj;`. As far as I understand it, it creates a copy of `obj` and assign that copy to `x` — that is pass by value. Now If I change a property of `x` then it changes that property of the obj object too. E.g.

```
x.len = 99
```

Then both `obj.len` and `x.len` become `99`. On the other hand consider this scenario:

```
var r = 2, s = 3, t = 4; 
s = r;
s = 88;
```

Now `r` is passed by value to `s` that `s` a copy of `r` was given to `s`. So changing `s` to `88` doesn't change the original value of `r` variable. Typing `r` in the console still gives `2`.

**Question 1:** If variables (objects included) are passed by value in JavaScript then why does changing `x.len` change the original `obj.len`, too?

Another problem is that I cannot change an object's property when assigning to a variable. Consider this scenario:

```
var obj2 = {
        len: 4,
        bred: 5
    }
var x2;
x2 = obj.len;
```

Now typing `x2` in console simply returns `4`. But if I try to change the value of `x2` such as `x2 = 77;` then that doesn't change `obj2.len`.

**Question2:** Why can't I change object's property with a variable?

Comment: What you describe in your first paragraph is not a passage by value, it is by reference.

Comment: Only objects are of Reference Data type I believe.`var xyz` are Primitive data types.

Comment: A good read here http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is passed by value, but when you create an object you get an reference to that object.

```
// Create an object. Assign a reference to that object to `obj`
var obj = {
    len: 4,
    bred: 5
};
// Copy the value of `obj` to `x`. Now `x` is also a reference to that object.
var x = obj;
```

Any changes to properties of `x` or `obj` will now modify the same object because they go through copies of the same reference.

---

```
var obj2 = {
    len: 4,
    bred: 5
}
var x2;
x2 = obj.len;
```

`len` is a number, not an object, so the value isn't a reference. So when you copy it you get a copy of the number (instead of a copy of the reference to the object).

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, null, undefined and symbols) are passed by value; objects are also passed by value, but the value passed is that of their reference.

> As far as I understand it, it creates a copy of obj and assign that copy to x -- that is pass by value.

No, `x` is assigned a copy of the value of the reference to `obj`. `x` then points to `obj`. Modifications made via either reference will then modify the same object.

`obj.len`, on the other hand, contains a primitive, so the value of itself is copied.