# Can't declare variable as object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am declaring a function that, when given a string as an argument, returns an object where keys are the words in the string. Values are the # of occurrences of that word in the string.

When I run the below code, I get {}.

```
function countWords(string) {
  var result = {};
  var words = string.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var currentElement = words[i];
    var prop = result[currentElement];
    if(prop) {
        prop += 1;
    } else {
        prop = 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(countWords('hello hello')); // => {'hello': 2}
```

However, replacing `prop = 1` with `result[CurrentElement] = 1` returns the expected answer.

Why is it wrong to use prop = 1 in this context?

Comment: `prop` is just a variable. If you assign it to some property, then write `prop = 1`, you just redefine `prop` to be `1`. You don’t actually touch the property itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are variables/objects passed by value and why can't I change object's property with variable in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865168/are-variables-objects-passed-by-value-and-why-cant-i-change-objects-property-w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var prop = result[currentElement];`
This makes a copy of the value in `result[currentElement]` into `prop`, then you add one but never put it back into the array. The assignment is by value, not by reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the reference to the object for checking and incrementing.

```
result[currentElement]
^^                      object
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  property of object
```

If you just get the value of it, you get a primitive value and not the wanted reference to the object.

```
value = result[currentElement] // undefined in the first call
                               //         1 in the second call
```

but you do not have a reference to result anymore.

```js
function countWords(string) {
  var result = {};
  var words = string.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var currentElement = words[i];
    if (result[currentElement]) {
      result[currentElement] += 1;
    } else {
      result[currentElement] = 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(countWords('hello hello')); // => {'hello': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
var prop = result[currentElement];
```

you are copying the value of `result[currentElement]` (apparently a number) and then increment the copy, thus th original value (`result[currentElement]`) remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Because variables are almost never linked by reference with anything else.**

There are only 2 cases when it goes in other way:

1. `arguments` in nonstrict mode.

   ```js
   function f(a) {
     console.log(a, arguments[0]);
     a = 10;
     console.log(a, arguments[0]);
   }

   function g(a) {
     'use strict';
     console.log(a, arguments[0]);
     a = 10;
     console.log(a, arguments[0]);
   }

   f(7);
   g(7);
   ```
2. Left side of assignment including decomposition.

   ```js
   var a = 8, b = 10;
   console.log(a, b);
   [a, b] = [b, a];
   console.log(a, b);

   var x = [0, 1, 2];
   console.log(x.join(" "));
   [x[1], x[0], x[2]] = x;
   console.log(x.join(" "));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add it in the result like this :

```
<script>
    function countWords(string) {
  var result = {};
  var words = string.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var currentElement = words[i];
    var prop = result[currentElement];
    if(prop) {
        prop += 1;
    } else {
        prop = 1;
    }
    result[currentElement]=prop;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(countWords('hello hello test khalil'));
</script>
```